# Pyspark - Modify random subset of row values from a list of Strings

Tags: pyspark

Below code randomly changes the *State* to be one of the Strings in *state_list*.

```
state_list = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']

def random_string():
    return random.choice(state_list)

def update_df(df):
    random_string_udf = udf(random_string, StringType())
    df = df.withColumn('State', lit(random_string_udf()))
    df.show()

update_df(df)
```

It does this for all rows in the DF.

But how to modify only a random subset of rows (say 50% of rows each time) ?

Tried:

```
df = df.withColumn('State', when(df.State.like('%ADY%'), lit(random_string_udf())).otherwise(df.State))
```

But this changes based on a condition which is NOT random.

And:

```
df = df.withColumn('State', when(random.randint(0, 1)) == 1), lit(random_string_udf()).otherwise()
```

But *when* requires a Column instead of a Boolean.

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT

Thanks to Ron Serruya the following works

```
df = df.withColumn('State', F.when(F.rand() <= F.lit(0.5), F.shuffle(state_array)[0]))
```

And then added an otherwise condition so existing values don't change.

```
df = df.withColumn('State', F.when(F.rand() <= F.lit(0.5), F.shuffle(state_array)[0]).otherwise(df.State))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing spark functions with python functions, instead you need to use spark's random, like this

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('State', F.when(F.rand() <= F.lit(0.5)), random_string_udf())
```

This will generate a random number between 0 and 1, and when its under 0.5 (~50% of the time) it will add the random state, otherwise it will be null

Other than that, instead of using a python udf to get a random state you can use spark functions for better performance

```py
state_list = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
state_array = F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in state_list])

df = df.withColumn('State', F.when(F.rand() <= F.lit(0.5)), F.shuffle(state_array)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked almost out of the box. Just a small change wrt brackets

df = df.withColumn('State', F.when(F.rand() <= F.lit(0.5), F.shuffle(state_array)[0]))